# Ansible copies private key to the remote dest host

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ansible

We are integrating jenkins with ansible, and found out that when we copy files from source to destination hosts, we create also redundant files such as:

We have `some_dir` directory in `{{jenkins_workspace}}/src/files/some_dir` path and we just need to copy it from time to time.

Our playbook sample:

```
tasks:
    - name: Create or validate remote group
      ansible.builtin.group:
        name: "{{ remote_group }}"
        state: present

    - name: create or validate 'remote user' user
      ansible.builtin.user:
        name: "{{ remote_user }}"
        group: "{{ remote_group }}"
        home: "{{ remote_host_dir }}"

    - name: Copy file to server
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: "{{jenkins_workspace}}/src/files/"
        dest: "{{ remote_host_dir }}"
        owner: {{ remote_user }}
        group: "{{ remote_group }}"
        mode: '0660'
```

As a result we get the following directories:

{{jenkins_workspace}}/src/files:

- some_dir // a directory with some files inside

  - files

- ssh12345.sh  // a file with a single `#! /bin/sh`  line
- ssh5678.key  // our private ssh key

Files `ssh12345.sh` and `ssh5678.key` are redundant and we don't need them. And by the way, they are only created once we add the `ansible.builtin.copy` or `ansible.builtin.copy.synchronize` modules.

What can be the reason for such weird issue?

Comment: You are using the Ansible plugin for Jenkins? It could be populating those files in the workspace if I recall correctly.

Comment: Yes, we are using this plugin. How do we disable this?

Comment: You could instead copy the files out of the retrieved role directory instead of the workspace itself.